# Storing visiting IP addresses in document array or seperate collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection Items. Each document in this collection has a view counter, that increments every time a user who hasn't viewed the item earlier, visits its page.

Currently, I am storing an array of ipaddresses in each item document, so that I can keep track of who has viewed it, and only increment the view counter when a new user visits.

I am however concerned that this may affect performance since I have no way of retrieving the item document, without also getting the IP array.

I expect this array to range between 1 - 5000.

Would I be better off having a separate collection with an item id and the array, or am i overblowing the potential performance risks?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [official documentation.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#data-model-design)

> In general, embedding provides better performance for read operations, as well as the ability to request and retrieve related data in a single database operation. Embedded data models make it possible to update related data in a single atomic write operation.
>
> However, embedding related data in documents may lead to situations where documents grow after creation. Document growth can impact write performance and lead to data fragmentation

Since your array size will grow embedding your document is not a good option.
You may want to go for [One-to-One Relationships](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/#model-one-to-one-relationships-with-embedded-documents)